# user permissions in shared folder

Tags: permissions, ssh, home-directory

I have a pair of users on an ssh Server. lets call them UserX & UserY.
UserX has the home Dir /home/userX
UserY has the home Dir /home/userX
Both are members of the userX group. 
UserX has no problems, everything is cool, and working fine.
UserY may read Files in his home directory, but cannot write files.

How can I give full access permissions (rwx) to UserY?

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod 771 -R /home/UserX
```

This will give rwx permissions to both the owner and the members of the group that the owner belongs to. The first 7 gives the owner rwx permissions, the second gives rwx to the group and the third bit is everyone else. The -R flag is the recursive option. Everyone else with just have execute permissions (Hence the third bit in the triplex there). You could change this if you wanted different permissions for the global user (not the owner or part of the group).

Alternatively you can use:

```
chmod g+rwxs /home/UserX
```

This will ensure that future files created in the directory are owned by the group and have rwx permissions.

Comment: Will this make future files and folders created by UserX accessible to UserY?

Comment: I have edited the answer